# Vue.js duda con camel case y pascal case

Tags: vue.js

Tengo una duda con respecto a vue.js
En el archivo app.vue puedo importar un componente usando Pascal case y luego llamandolo con kebab-case, pero en el hijo de ese componente esta convención propia de vue ya no funciona.

Por ejemplo en el archivo app.vue utilizo:
import ListView from './listView.vue' y puedo utilizarlo como <list-view"/> en el DOM.
Sin embargo si en el componente ListView.vue donde quiero importar listItem al importarlo como import ListItem from "./listItem.vue", me lanza error en consola de Uncaught ReferenceError: listItem is not defined porque no puedo utilizar en el DOM kebab-case () y no lo reconoce.

app.vue:

```
    <template>
    <div class="todoListContainer">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2 id="title"> Todo List</h2>
            <add-item-form/>
        </div>
        <list-view :items="items"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import addItemForm from "./addItemForm.vue";
import ListView from './listView.vue';


export default{
    components:{
        addItemForm,
        ListView,
        // ListItem
    },
    data: function(){
        return{
            items: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getList(){
            axios.get('api/items')
            .then(response=>{
                this.items = response.data
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.getList();
    }
    
}
</script>
```

ListView.vue

```
 <template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
            <list-item
            :item="item"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ListItem from "./listItem.vue";


export default {
    props: ['items'],
    components:{
        listItem
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no está encontrando la referencia a la hora de llamar al componente, lo estás llamando en camel case y lo tienes definido en pascal case a la hora de importarlo, es solo modificarlo.

Tu lista de components quedaria de esta forma

> `components: { ListItem }`